# Javascript - Numeric input to obtain variable length array data

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a dozen arrays (hypothetically) and each has a completely different length. Is there a way that I can name them such that a numeric input into a function will return an array corresponding to that specific number?

This makes no sense so here's kinda what I want:

```
var dQw4w9WgXcQ;
const array1 = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1];
const array2 = [1,2,3,4];
const array3 = [1,3,6];

function getArray(id){
    output = constNamed('array' + id);
}

//getArray(2) sets dQw4w9WgXcQ to [1,2,3,4]
```

and yes, dQw4w9WgXcQ is just something I totally typed on accident

Comment: "yes, dQw4w9WgXcQ is just something I totally typed on accident" then why are you keeping it?

Comment: youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ

Answer (score 0):

**`USING OBJECT`**

**1)** You can creat an object that contain all arrays as:

```
const arrays = {
  array1,
  array2,
  array3,
};
```

**2)** Assign the result `getArray(2)` to `dQw4w9WgXcQ` by just returning the array from object.

```
return arrays[`array${id}`];
```

```js
var dQw4w9WgXcQ;
const array1 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1];
const array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const array3 = [1, 3, 6];

function getArray(id) {
  const arrays = {
    array1,
    array2,
    array3,
  };
  return arrays[`array${id}`];
}

dQw4w9WgXcQ = getArray(2);
console.log(dQw4w9WgXcQ);
```

**NOTE: If you want to set value to `dQw4w9WgXcQ` directly after the invocation of the function `getArray(2)`**

```js
var dQw4w9WgXcQ;
const array1 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1];
const array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const array3 = [1, 3, 6];

function getArray(id) {
  const arrays = {
    array1,
    array2,
    array3,
  };
  dQw4w9WgXcQ = arrays[`array${id}`];
}

getArray(2);
console.log(dQw4w9WgXcQ);
```

**`USING ARRAY`**

```js
var dQw4w9WgXcQ;
const array1 = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1];
const array2 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const array3 = [1, 3, 6];

function getArray(id) {
  const arrays = [array1, array2, array3];
  return arrays[id - 1];
}

dQw4w9WgXcQ = getArray(2);
console.log(dQw4w9WgXcQ);
```

Comment: Why not use an array `const arrays = [array1, array2, array3]`?

Comment: I down voted. I felt that following OP:s bad example of assigning to global variables inside functions isn't something that we should encourage. But you have changed your answer and i no longer feel that the down vote is necessary.

Comment: Dude, There are multiple solutions to a problem, So why do you think it is better to use an array. Just curious.

Comment: My comment about arrays was just a comment. I wanted to know your reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

Have one array contain all the arrays. You can then pass that array into the function as an argument along with the id, and use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to return the array at the index of `id - 1` (because indexes are zero-based). If `find` can't meet the condition it will return `undefined`.

```js
const arr = [
  [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],
  [1,2,3,4],
  [1,3,6]
];

function getArray(arr, id){
  return arr.find((a, index) => index === id - 1);
}

console.log(getArray(arr, 2));
console.log(getArray(arr, 4));
```

Note all we're doing here is assigning